# Android prompt user input dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I would like to prompt the user to give me input in my android application using a dialog.
When the user puts the figure it will go to another screen, but it does not give the user to input the value it does not waiting to the user its going to another activity directly.
What can i do to waiting  the user to input the value he needs and after that it will take the user to the activity he needs. This is the code that i use.

```
else
  {
   {
    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Login.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_input_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.editCodeSurvey);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
     .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        String surveyCode = editText.getText().toString();
                                            }
                                        })
     .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                });
    // create an alert dialog
   AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
   alert.show();
   }
   //After Creating Dialog then we asking if the User that signed in is a manager
   if(parseUser.getBoolean("isManager"))
   {
    //open manager Class
    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,ManagerScreen.class));
   }
   else{
    //open Student Class to fill the survey
    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,StudentField.class));
    }
```

Comment: put your user-validation and `startActivity` into the dialog-button listener. So it will be triggered, when the user clicks the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not waiting for user input. You need to put code of launching new activity inside the Dialog box listener.

Put

```
//After Creating Dialog then we asking if the User that signed in is a manager
if(parseUser.getBoolean("isManager"))
{
    //open manager Class
    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,ManagerScreen.class));
}
else{
    //open Student Class to fill the survey
    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,StudentField.class)); 
}
```

inside `onClick` of OK button. It should be like this

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    String surveyCode = editText.getText().toString();
    //After Creating Dialog then we asking if the User that signed in is a manager
    if(parseUser.getBoolean("isManager"))
    {
        //open manager Class
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,ManagerScreen.class));
    }
    else{
        //open Student Class to fill the survey
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,StudentField.class)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    String surveyCode = editText.getText().toString();

    if(parseUser.getBoolean("isManager")) {
        //open manager Class
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,ManagerScreen.class));
    } else {
        //open Student Class to fill the survey
        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,StudentField.class));
    }
}
```

put the code inside on click method